Create simple quickfix/j acceptor in integration test
I have an application with a fix initiator connecting to a remote server. I am trying to create(integration tests) where I create a fix acceptor connect to my initiator and send fix messages. I was able to create a blank fix acceptor using quickfixj.spring.boot.starter and these configurations:


[default]
FileStorePath=target/data/executor
ConnectionType=acceptor
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
HeartBtInt=30
ValidOrderTypes=1,2,F
SenderCompID=TEST_SENDER
TargetCompID=TEST_TARGET
UseDataDictionary=Y
DefaultMarketPrice=12.30
FileLogPath=logs-server

[session]
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
DefaultApplVerID=9
SocketAcceptPort=9999



In this case, the connection is established but when trying to create an acceptor using core-quickfix gets an error that can't establish a connection.
Can someone give me a simple guide on how to do it, not just code but also a little explanation like


create a server, start the server
create a fixed connection, start the connection


